# Equation for calculating boolean answer to "is this Earth satellite in eclipse"

Tags: the-sun, orbital-mechanics, mathematics, python, artificial-satellite

I have found plenty of math for determining duration of satellite eclipse, but I am having trouble finding an equation that produces a simple boolean answer to the question "Is this Earth satellite in eclipse?", given either position and velocity vectors or a TLE + epoch.

**Does there exist an equation for determining if any given Earth satellite is in eclipse, given its position/velocity at epoch?**

Comment: The source code for Vallado's book has the computation.  Of course the equations are in the book, perhaps someone will post them. http://celestrak.org/software/vallado-sw.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Greg suggested in the comments, there was indeed an equation in Vallado's book:

[image: Part 1 of Algorithm 34, from Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications (Vallado 2013)]
[image: Part 2 of Algorithm 34, from Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications (Vallado 2013)]

See [my answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55531/47994) to [my own question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55519/47994) for information on the Python implementation of it, as well as the assumptions made about the input.